# How do I detect the left and right side of my screen?

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing a project for my kitten who died...
I would like to know how I make it flip (look at the right side) when it comes to the left side of the screen, I'll leave an example in the print

[image: EXAMPLE]
[image: EXAMPLE 2]

Comment: You need to provide more information. Most importantly, what technology are you using and what exactly do you want to change direction and with respect to what? My guess would be that it is Windows Forms. Assuming so, is it a form moving and you want to detect the edge of the screen or the whole desktop, or is it a control moving and you want to detect the edge of the form? Please take the site tour and spend some time in the Help Center to learn what is required and edit your question accordingly. This is better than many first efforts but is still lacking important details.

Comment: Actually, I think I misinterpreted the question initially. I think that, rather than detecting the edge, you want to detect the middle and which side of that you're on. Is that correct? We still need the other information.

Comment: Also, what exactly are you asking for? The detection and the "flipping" are two different things and so a single question must only be asking about one of them. If you need help with both, that's two separate questions.

Comment: I'm programming in Windows Forms, inside the Form there's a PictureBox with this cat inside, I just want to know how to move my cat to the left side of the screen, turn it to the right side (look to the right side), as if he was positioning himself to see with me. My project is for my kitten, who unfortunately died.

Comment: Firstly, no one should have to read the comments to understand the question. If you have additional or clarifying information to provide then update the question. Secondly, that explanation is still not as clear as it could be. It sounds like you mean that you're moving the `PictureBox` within the form and you care about the location of the `PictureBox` with respect to the entire screen, but it could still be interpreted differently. I'm going to provide an answer on that basis and, if I have misinterpreted, then hopefully that will be a lesson to describe your problem clearly in the future.

Comment: To be more specific, you say *"I just want to know how to move my cat"* but you're not moving your cat. You're either moving the form within the screen or the `PictureBox` within the form. That there's an image of a cat in the `PictureBox` is nice for context but is ultimately irrelevant to the technical problem. We need to know the details of the technical problem in order to provide a technical solution. What you're actually moving in relation to what is part of the technical details.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code you can use to start with a single image file and display it in its original form or flipped horizontally depending on the horizontal position of its `PictureBox` on the screen.

```vb
'The Image to display on the left side of the screen.
Private leftImage As Image

'The Image to display on the right side of the screen.
Private rightImage As Image

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Assume that the original image is the one to display on the left.
    leftImage = Image.FromFile("file path here")

    'Create a mirror image to display on the right.
    rightImage = leftImage.Clone()
    rightImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX)
End Sub

Private Function IsPictureBoxOnLeftSideOfScreen() As Boolean
    Dim screenMiddle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width \ 2
    Dim pictureBoxMiddle = PictureBox1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty).X + PictureBox1.Width \ 2

    Return screenMiddle > pictureBoxMiddle
End Function

Private Sub SetImage()
    PictureBox1.Image = If(IsPictureBoxOnLeftSideOfScreen(), leftImage, rightImage)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    rightImage.Dispose()
    leftImage.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Where you call that `SetImage` method depends on exactly how you're moving the `PictureBox`, which you never showed us. If you're moving the form then you might do so in the `LocationChanged` event handler of the form. If you're moving the `PictureBox` then you might do so in the `LocationChanged` event handler of the `PictureBox`.